# Send microphone's audio to the server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to record audio from microphone, convert it in a base64 string and then send it to the server.

The server then convert the base64 string in a .wav file.

My C# code:

```
   IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage);
   fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Position);

   fileStream.Position = 0;



        // Convert to base64 string and then urlencode it:

byte[] binaryData = new Byte[fileStream.Length];
long bytesRead = fileStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
string fileBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);               
fileBase64 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileBase64);



        // Send it to server:


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.../upload.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

        string postData = String.Format("file={0}", fileBase64);   

        // Getting the request stream.
        request.BeginGetRequestStream
            (result =>
            {
                // Sending the request.
                using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(postData);
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }

                // Getting the response.
                request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                {
                    var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string srresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }, null);
            }, null);
```

My php script then receive a base64 string like "+/8cADkAOQAWAPD/7f/5..." and then convert it in a .wav file with **base64_decode** php function. But if I open this file with VLC, it doesn't reproduce anything.

If instead I open the file in this way ( see below ), just after I saved it, then it reproduce the sound:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(duration)];
 using (IsolatedStorageFile userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream openfilestream = userStore.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                openfilestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

  SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(buffer, microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
  soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
  soundIsPlaying = true;
  soundInstance.Play();
```

Comment: You're saving (and playing with SoundEffect) raw audio data. WAVE file isn't just data but it has header too (as a bitmap file isn't just a sequence of pixels). If you want to play it with a program then you need to save it with header (Google for specs). You're lucky it's a simple file format and header is just a bunch of bytes (format, frequency, channels).

Answer (score 1):

You're saving (and playing with `SoundEffect`) raw audio data.

WAVE file isn't just data but it has header too (as a bitmap file isn't just a sequence of pixels). If you want to play it with a program then you need to save it with header: see [specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV).

You're lucky it's pretty easy format so you can do something like this (untested and pretty raw just for illustration purposes, you have to do it server side when you convert raw stream to a WAVE):

```
// First 4 bytes are file format marker. Container file format
// is RIFF (it's a tagged file format)
streamWriter.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));

// Number of bytes, header + audio samples
streamWriter.Write(36 + sampleCount * channelCount * samplingRate);

// Beginning of chunk specific of WAVE files, it describe how
// data are stored
streamWriter.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVEfmt "));
streamWriter.Write(16); // It's always 16 bytes

// Audio stream is PCM (value 1)
streamWriter.Write((UInt16)1);

// Player will use these information to understand how samples
// are stored in the stream.
streamWriter.Write(channelCount);
streamWriter.Write(samplingRate);
streamWriter.Write(samplingRate * bytesPerSample * channelCount);
streamWriter.Write(bytesPerSample * channelCount);
streamWriter.Write((UInt16)(8 * bytesPerSample));

// Now the chunk that contains audio stream, just add its marker
// and its length then write all your samples (in the raw format you have)
streamWriter.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data"));
streamWriter.Write(sampleCount * bytesPerSample);
```

Comment: what are channelcount, samplingRate, sampleCount, ecc ?

Comment: What name implies :) number of channels in your acquired stream (1 = mono, 2 = stereo); samplingRate...well number of samples per second; sampleCount = number of acquired samples (= duration in seconds * samplingRate * channelCount)

Comment: and how I know what is samplingRate for my recorded audio file ? thanks :)

Comment: @xRobot you have them all in your code. samplingRate is microphone.SampleRate. BTW check RIFF+Wave specifications (or Google for some ready code), this example is pretty raw and untested!